# Add Filter to Ignore a Post/Page or a Number of Post/Pages

Tags: pages, filters, search

Hoping someone can assist but as part of normal WordPress theme searching, how can I add a filter as part of the search to not include certain posts/pages as part of my LOOP?

For example, I want the "Search" to ignore post=234 as part of the loop or posts 123,234,555?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pre_get_posts` filter hook and set the `post__not_in` parameter of the query ex:

```
function exclude_from_search_filter($query) {
        if ( !$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) {
                $query->set('post__not_in', array(40, 9) ); // id of page or post
        }
        return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_from_search_filter' );
```